# How transactions and entityManager work with JPA and Google Guice?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, guice

I am using JPA/Hibernate with Google Guice. 
I am facing doubts:
 1) Will I have to close entity manager ?
 2) When will I need to begin Transaction and commit?
 3) For a service request there can be multiple DAO's requests to serve the request, In that case should I need to begin and close transaction or will it handle automatically?

Service Class :

```
public class StudentService {

@Transactional
public Integer updateStudentName(int id, String name) {
     Student student = studentDAO.getById(id);
     student.setName(name);
     studentDAO.update(student);
     Account account = AccountDAO.getById(id);
     account.setAccountHolderName(name);
     accountDAO.update(account);
}

@Transactional
public void communicateViaMultipleDAOs(..... multiple Constraints) {
   DAO1.updateBySomeConstraints(....);
   DAO2.updateBySomeConstraints(....);
   DAO3.updateBySomeConstraints(....);
}

}
```

Student DAO:

```
public interface StudentDAO {
     void update(Student student);
     Student getById(int id);
     void updateByOtherParam(String name, String balance);
}


public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

   Provider<EntityManager> entityManagerProvider;

   public getEntityManager(){
       return entityManagerProvider.get();
   }

   void update(Student student) {
   }

   Student getById(int id) {
   }

   void updateByOtherParam(String name, String balance) {
       EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
       /**
       Intializing CriteriaBuilder
       Doing Join
       Adding predicates ( condition in where clause)
       executing update
       **/ 
   }
}
```

Similarly, there are lots of other DAOs.
In above DAO's , I am just getting EntityManager and doing update/select operation.
I am not using 
entityManager.getTransaction().begin() ,
entityManager.getTransaction().commit() ,
entityManager.close().

Will it create any issues?

In above Service layer function updateStudentName():

I am first getting and object then updating it.But there maybe case some other thread also read the same value before updating the value.How to avoid this situation?

Comment: What a library does implement behaviour for this annotation `@Transactional`?

Comment: @v.ladynev see [this](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Transactions) for Transactional implementation in guice